# How do I make sidebar automatically disappear once a menu item clicked

Tags: reactjs, onclick, sidebar, react-sidebar

[image: SideBar Image with subMenu options]

I implemented a some Sidebar code and would like the sidebar to automatically close once an item is clicked. Currently have to click the 'X' to hide sidebar.  Below is the existing code for the Sidebar and Sidebar sub-menu.

Probably a one line fix if you know what you are doing, but I am new to React, so any help would be appreciated.

...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData';
import SubMenu from './SubMenu';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons/lib';

const Nav = styled.div`
  // background: #15171c;
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
`;

const NavIcon = styled(Link)`
  margin-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
`;
//  background: #15171c;

const SidebarNav = styled.nav`
  background: #15171c;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: ${({ sidebar }) => (sidebar ? '0' : '-100%')};
  transition: 350ms;
  z-index: 10;
`;

const SidebarWrap = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
`;

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        
        <Nav>
          <NavIcon to='#'>
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </NavIcon>
        </Nav>
        <SidebarNav sidebar={sidebar}>
          <SidebarWrap>
            <NavIcon to='#'>
              <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose onClick={showSidebar} />
            </NavIcon>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return <SubMenu item={item} key={index} />;
            })}
          </SidebarWrap>
        </SidebarNav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
 
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const SidebarLink = styled(Link)`
  display: flex;
  color: #e1e9fc;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;

  //#c6c8cf
  //#252831
  &:hover {
    background: #c6c8cf;
    border-left: 4px solid #632ce4;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const SidebarLabel = styled.span`
  margin-left: 16px;
`;

const DropdownLink = styled(Link)`
  background: #414757;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 18px;

//  background: #632ce4;

  &:hover {
    background: #d9dbd5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const SubMenu = ({ item }) => {
  const [subnav, setSubnav] = useState(false);

  const showSubnav = () => setSubnav(!subnav);

  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}>
        <div>
          {item.icon}
          <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
        </div>
        <div>
          {item.subNav && subnav
            ? item.iconOpened
            : item.subNav
            ? item.iconClosed
            : null}
        </div>
      </SidebarLink>
      {subnav &&
        item.subNav.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <DropdownLink to={item.path} key={index}>
              {item.icon}
              <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
            </DropdownLink>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default SubMenu;

import React from 'react';
// import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import * as IoIcons from 'react-icons/io';
import * as RiIcons from 'react-icons/ri';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';

export const SidebarData = [
  {
    title: 'Login',
    path: '/login',
    icon: <AiIcons.AiOutlineLogin />,
  },
  {
    title: 'Site Master',
    path: '/list-sitemaster',
    icon: <FaIcons.FaBroadcastTower />,
  },
  {
    title: 'Site Report Cards',
    path: '/sitereportcardmaster',
    icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
   
  },
  {
    title: 'Report Card Master',
    path: '/reportcardmaster',
    icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />
  },
  {
    title: 'Categories',
    path: '/categories',
    icon: <IoIcons.IoIosClipboard />,

    iconClosed: <RiIcons.RiArrowDownSFill />,
    iconOpened: <RiIcons.RiArrowUpSFill />,

    subNav: [
      {
        title: 'Asset Type',
        path: '/assettype',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Asset Sub Type',
        path: '/assetsubtype',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Document Type',
        path: '/documenttype',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Document Sub Type',
        path: '/documentsubtype',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Report Card Category',
        path: '/reportcarddetailcategory',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Contact Detail Type',
        path: '/contactdetailtype',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lighting Type',
        path: '/lightingtype',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Company Master',
    path: '/cpymaster-toplevel',
    icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />,
    iconClosed: <RiIcons.RiArrowDownSFill />,
    iconOpened: <RiIcons.RiArrowUpSFill />,

    subNav: [
      {
        title: 'CompanyMaster',
        path: '/cpymaster',
        icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Users',
        path: '/users',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPerson />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Contacts',
        path: '/contactmaster',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPeople />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'My Profile',
    path: '/add-usersmall',
    icon: <AiIcons.AiOutlineUser/>,
  },
  {
    title: 'PDF',
    path: '/pdfcomponent',
    icon: <AiIcons.AiOutlineUser/>,
  },
  {
    title: 'Users PageSort Test',
    path: '/userstable',
    icon: <AiIcons.AiOutlineUser/>,
  },
  {
    title: 'Logout',
    path: '/logout',
    icon: <AiIcons.AiOutlineLogin />,
  }
];
```

...

Comment: This is too much code. Can you provide only the code for the sidebar, the 'X' that closes it currently, and an item that you want to close the sidebar on click? See this guide on structuring a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You have a state for the sidebar in

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
...
```

If I'm not wrong, you close it in

```
 <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose onClick={showSidebar} />
```

You can pass down that showSidebar function to the link components, somthing like

```
<SubMenu item={item} key={index} toggleSidebar={showSidebar}/>
```

(Also, avoid using index as key)
Receiving the funtion in the SubMenu component

```
const SubMenu = ({ item,toggleSidebar }) => {
```

thus, you are able to use it in the link

Comment: Half way there !
In the SubMenu function I changed
'<DropdownLink to={item.path} key={index}>'
to
'<DropdownLink to={item.path} key={index} onClick={toggleSidebar}>'

Now if a sub-menu item is selected the SideBar DOES disappear - Awesome.

I need help on where to place similar code to make the SideBar disappear when a main menu item is selected (that does not have a sub-menu).

Does it have something to do with the following line of code?
'      <SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}>'
@daniel

Comment: I added image of SideBar menu with subMenu options displayed for reference. @daniel

Comment: Seems like a conditional onClick, but I  dont  know the syntax
`onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}  OR onClick={toggleSidebar}`
@daniel

Comment: Sorry @HighwayRob, I just saw your comments. I think it is easier to associate the function directly onclick={toggleSidebar}, rather than having a condition (&&), but if needed, you could define the function with the condition and associate it with the onclick.

Comment: I posted a solution. Just had to get the toggleSidebar in the correct place.  Thank you for your support and interest. @daniel

Answer (score 0):

The following code in the subMenu.js along with @Daniel toggleSidebar code in sideBar.js rendered the desired results.

...

```
  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}>
        <div>
          {item.icon}
          {/*following onClick={toggleSidebar} allows mainm menu items without subnav to close sidebar */}
          <SidebarLabel onClick={toggleSidebar}>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
        </div>
        <div>
          {item.subNav && subnav
            ? item.iconOpened
            : item.subNav
            ? item.iconClosed
            : null}
        </div>
      </SidebarLink>
      {subnav &&
        item.subNav.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            //following onClick={toggleSidebar} allows submenu selections to close sidebar
            <DropdownLink to={item.path} key={index} onClick={toggleSidebar}>
              {item.icon} 
              <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
            </DropdownLink>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
```

...